# Invoke a web service on HTTPS from a worklight adapter

Tags: web-services, https, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter, app-certification-kit

I need to know if there is a way in worklight 6.0 to invoke a web service on HTTPS from a worklight adapter without put the certificate inside a Java keystore and configure Worklight to use said keystore.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can invoke backend server using HTTPS, just set the protocol to "https" in adapter xml file. 
But if your backend server uses self signed certificate you need to import its public key into WL keystore configured in worklight.properties file (/server/conf folder)